# Count of duplicate values in array php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this Array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Num] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [Num] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [Num] => 13 ) [3] => Array ( [Num] => 2 ) [4] => Array ( [Num] => 3 ) [5] => Array ( [Num] => 3 ) [6] => Array ( [Num] => 1 ) [7] => Array ( [Num] => 44 ) )
```

And i want to get the number of duplicate values for example that array have 5 values duplicated.
simple way for this problem??help me!

php code:

```
$count = 0;
$temp = array();
for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($Num);$i++){
    for($j=$i+1;$j<=sizeof($Num);$j++){
        if($Num[$i]==$Num[$j]){
            $count++;
            $temp[]=$Num[$j];
        }
    }
}
var_dump($temp);
echo $count;
```

Comment: Will $Num always be an array of array each having only the element `Num`?

Comment: @VolkerK Yes only one element --> `Num`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it without fancy stuff, but it should work:

```
/**
 * Check if value exists in array
 */
function value_exists($array, $value) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($array as $v) {
        if($v['Num'] == $value) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    if ($count > 1) {
        return $count;
    }
}

$duplicated = array();
foreach ($Num as $key => $array ) {
    if($count = value_exists($Num, $array['Num'] )) {
        $duplicated[] = $array['Num'];
    }
}

echo 'Duplicated: ' . count($duplicated);
```

Comment: your code return `2`, But i want return `5` (Count of duplicate values)

Comment: duplicate values: `2,3,2,3,3`  and count of duplicate values `5`

Comment: @FatemehNamkhah it was counting items instead of values, updated, its fine now

Answer (score 1):

As of php 5.5 (because of [array_column](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)*) you can use

```
<?php
$num = array (
    array ( 'Num' => 2 ), array ( 'Num' => 3 ), array ( 'Num' => 13 ), array ( 'Num' => 2 ),
    array ( 'Num' => 3 ),   array ( 'Num' => 3 ),   array ( 'Num' => 1 ), array ( 'Num' => 44 ) 
);

$x = array_filter(
    array_count_values(
        array_column($num, 'Num')
    ),
    function($e) { return $e>1; }
);
var_export($x);
```

i.e.
- get all the elements 'Num' in $num as a "flat, 1-d" array.
- count the occurence of each value
- only keep count()>1 in the array

--
* in the user contributes notes for array_column there are fill-ins for php <5.5
And since you only have one element per array in $num you could also use array_map/array_shift

edit: a more verbose version without array_column

```
<?php
$num = array (
    array ( 'Num' => 2 ), array ( 'Num' => 3 ), array ( 'Num' => 13 ), array ( 'Num' => 2 ),
    array ( 'Num' => 3 ),   array ( 'Num' => 3 ),   array ( 'Num' => 1 ), array ( 'Num' => 44 ) 
);
// first remove the superfluous second dimension
$num = array_map(function($e) { return $e['Num']; }, $num); // -> $num = [ 2,3,13,2,3,3,1,44]
$num = array_count_values($num); // -> $num = [2=>2, 3=>3, 13=>1, 1=>1, 44=>1]
$num = array_filter($num, function($e) { return $e>1; }); // -> $num = [2=>2, 3=>3]

printf('There are %d duplicate values. A total of %d elements are doublets',
    count($num), array_sum($num)
);
```

prints `There are 2 duplicate values. A total of 5 elements are doublets`

Comment: your code return `array ( 2 => 2, 3 => 3, )` but i want count of duplicate value and i want return `5`

Comment: my version of php == 5.3.28

Comment: `i want return 5` throw in another array_sum ;-) "php == 5.3.28" - use the fill-ins

Comment: duplicate values: `2,3,2,3,3`  and count of duplicate values `5`

Comment: yeah, yeah, there's you copy&paste version.

Answer (score 0):

for PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7

```
$Num = array ( 
        "0" => array ( 'Num' => 2 ),
        "1" => array ( 'Num' => 3 ), 
        "2" => array ( 'Num' => 13), 
        "3" => array ( 'Num' => 2 ), 
        "4" => array ( 'Num' => 3 ), 
        "5" => array ( 'Num' => 3 ), 
        "6" => array ( 'Num' => 1 ), 
        "7" => array ( 'Num' => 44 ) );

$subArr = array_column($Num, 'Num');
$countArr = array_count_values($subArr);//array with all count
$filteredArr = array_filter($countArr, function ($val) {return $val > 1;});//filter that is having duplicates
echo "Count of Duplicate : ".array_sum($filteredArr);
```

else

```
$Num = array ( 
        "0" => array ( 'Num' => 2 ),
        "1" => array ( 'Num' => 3 ), 
        "2" => array ( 'Num' => 13), 
        "3" => array ( 'Num' => 2 ), 
        "4" => array ( 'Num' => 3 ), 
        "5" => array ( 'Num' => 3 ), 
        "6" => array ( 'Num' => 1 ), 
        "7" => array ( 'Num' => 44 ) );
$countArr = array();
foreach ($Num AS $eachArr) {
    $countArr[$eachArr['Num']] += 1;
}

$filteredArr = array_filter($countArr, function ($val) {return $val > 1;});//filter that is having duplicates
echo "Count of Duplicate : ".array_sum($filteredArr);
```